# Как увеличить переменную long money

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

У меня есть переменная:
public long money;
В неё может вместиться максимум 1000000000000000000 или 1Q
Мне этого не хватает, можно как-то её увеличить?

Comment: В целочисленном формате `ulong.MaxValue` - это максимум. Если надо больше, создайте свой тип и его логику, так же обратите внимание на тип `decimal`. Еще есть [такое](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/207754/).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ulong, как вам уже написали в комментариях или, если вы уже решили этот вопрос - закройте его.